# How to use a tab widget in Android?

Tags: android

Can anyone show me how to make a `tab widget` in Android?

Comment: This is standard material in the SDK tutorials. Have you even looked at them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a developer guide showing how to implement tabbed activities/fragments http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

It's very important to follow new solution, because the method using `TabActivity` is deprecated since API level 13.